# Python Requests get cookies values after authentication

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

in Python Requests 
How to get cookies values after authentication, the server must gave you a valid cookies after the authentication, in my case I can't see the cookies, even if I tried to look in .cookies or   .headers

Answer (score 0):

```
r = requests.get(url)
print r.cookies
```

the response contains an attribute cookies